# Display text inline from a separate container div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying make "the end" in the following code to appear inline with the lorem ipsum, and can't figure out how.  Is it possible?   I can't change the HTML structure at all. (nor can I add js, etc)

```css
#parent {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#block2 a {
  color: #00f;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="block1">
    <a> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur elit.  dolor nulla. Duis lob.</a>
  </div>
  <div id="block2">
    <a>The end</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want it to look like this:[image]

Comment: "I can't change the HTML structure at all" Does that include changing a div to a span?

Comment: yep, sadly.  I'm working within a rigid template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are able to make changes to the CSS, then this is an easy solution. Just use `display: inline`, which will make the element only take as much space as necessary (acting like a `<span>` element).

However, if by chance, you are unable to, then there is no way I can think of for you to achieve this given your situation.

```css
#parent {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#block1, #block2 {
  display: inline;
}

#block2 a {
  color: #00f;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="block1">
    <a> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur elit.  dolor nulla. Duis lob.</a>
  </div>
  <div id="block2">
    <a>The end</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh boy.  Yes, thank you.  I thought I had tried that, along with every other variation of `display: inline`.  I guess not.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the two block containers to `display: inline`:

```css
#parent {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#block2 a {
  color: #00f;
}

#block1, #block2 {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="block1">
    <a> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur elit.  dolor nulla. Duis lob.</a>
  </div>
  <div id="block2">
    <a>The end</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: no problem! everyone overlooks the simple stuff now and then